# How do I convert Array[Row] to RDD[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scenario where I want to convert the result of a dataframe which is in the format Array[Row] to RDD[Row]. I have tried using parallelize, but I don't want to use it as it needs to contain entire data in a single system which is not feasible in production box.

```
val Bid = spark.sql("select Distinct DeviceId, ButtonName  from stb").collect()
val bidrdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Bid)
```

How do I achieve this? I tried the approach given in this link ([How to convert DataFrame to RDD in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531224/how-to-convert-dataframe-to-rdd-in-scala)), but it didn't work for me.

```
val bidrdd1 = Bid.map(x => (x(0).toString, x(1).toString)).rdd
```

It gives an error `value rdd is not a member of Array[(String, String)]`

Answer (score 3):

The variable `Bid` which you've created here is **not** a DataFrame, it is an `Array[Row]`, that's why you can't use `.rdd` on it. If you want to get an `RDD[Row]`, simply call `.rdd` on the DataFrame (without calling `collect`):

```
val rdd = spark.sql("select Distinct DeviceId, ButtonName  from stb").rdd
```

Your post contains some misconceptions worth noting:

> ... a dataframe which is in the format Array[Row] ...

Not quite - the `Array[Row]` is the result of *collecting* the data from the DataFrame into Driver memory - it's not a DataFrame.

> ... I don't want to use it as it needs to contain entire data in a single system ...

Note that as soon as you use `collect` on the DataFrame, you've already collected entire data into a single JVM's memory. So using `parallelize` is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks Tzach, it worked. Currently I am working on test data, so I used collect. Final code will contain saving the result to flat file.

Comment: Using `collect` for testing is useful and appropriate, but make sure you separate the testing from your actual code - `collect` returns a completely different type that cannot be used as if `collect` wasn't called.